# Disable Predictive Text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I think this is a pretty simply question, but how do I disable the predictive text for an EditText in Android. Do I set a property in the EditText's XML or a property in the EditText's object... or both? Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the `inputType` property in the XML layout or call `setInputType()` with one or more (separated by `|`) of [those](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType) values.

To disable the suggestions use `text|textNoSuggestions`. However the Sense UI keyboard seems to ignore that, adding `textFilter` works here.